# Angular2 passing data to different components using services

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a date range which i would like to share the selected dates amongst different components without the need to duplicate code across all components

So i have architectured my application this way

```
<app-date-range /> //date range component
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have also created an event service which i have added in my app module providers

```
@Injectable()
export class ReportsEventService {

 public maininputrange = new Subject();
 constructor() { }

 maininputrangeemit(data:any){
   this.maininputrange.next({type:"mainputrange", data:data});
 }

}
```

IN my date range component i emit like this

```
  constructor(
   private _reportEventService:ReportsEventService
  ){ }

  dateRangeChanged(data){
    ...other implementations
    this._reportEventService.maininputrangeemit(this.mainInput);
  }
```

NOw i would like when i visit another component to access the data emitted on init.

```
  mainInput:any;
   constructor(
      private _reportsEvenService:ReportsEventService
    ) {
    _reportsEvenService.maininputrange.subscribe(
       (data)=>{
       console.log("receiving values"); //called many times
       this.mainInput = data;
      }
     )
   }

 ngOnInit() {
   console.log("maininput value is");
   console.log(this.mainInput); //always undefined

 }
```

Where am i going wrong and is my implementation possible?

Comment: use `BehaviourSubject` instead of `Subject`. I would prefer to set up redux(ngrx-store)

Comment: Thanks behaviour subject works.

Comment: happy coding. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to know what went wrong, here it is.
In you `ReportsEventService` you only have a setter method, you don't have a getter method to return the value.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ReportsEventService {

  public maininputrange = new Subject();
  constructor() {}

  setmaininputrangeemit(data: any) {
    this.maininputrange.next({
      type: "mainputrange",
      data: data
    });
  }

  getmaininputrangeemit(): Observalble < any > {
    return this.maininputrange.asObservable;
  }

}
```

```js
mainInput: any;
constructor(
  private _reportsEvenService: ReportsEventService
) {
  _reportsEvenService.getmaininputrange.subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log("receiving values"); //called many times
      this.mainInput = data;
    }
  )
}

ngOnInit() {
  console.log("maininput value is");
  console.log(this.mainInput); //always undefined

}
```